# Configuring Facebook Audience Network

Tags: android, facebook, ads, facebook-audience-network

I have an Android app that is currently using AdMob. I'm trying to integrate Facebook Audience Network but I'm a bit confused on how to do this.

It asks me to implement the SDK, and then they will review my app. How is this actually done? I'm I supposed to stop delivering AdMob ads and integrate facebook's, then publish my app and wait for them to review? They say only developers and testers will be able to view ads until it's reviewed. But how will my app knows which user is actually using it? My app doesn't have a login, it's just a simple app with a single view and a banner on the footer.

Any extra info you might have will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to answer but may be my experience helps others.

Note: I am writing my below answer in Jan,2019. may be below steps changes in the future.

First of all you have to have an account in business manager [here](https://business.facebook.com)

Steps:

1. Create property.
2. Integrate Audience Network.
3. Test ads in your app.
4. send app to be reviewed.

To Integrate Audience network ad you have two options:

1. Follow integration document as [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-banners) an example of banner ads
2. Or download Audience Network samples as [here](https://github.com/fbsamples/audience-network) and test all ad types.

For my self I always use second options with is more easy.

Note: for testing on real mobile , you have to have facebook installed on the mobile device.

after integration and testing you need to send the app for review.
Reviewing an app takes around one day.

That's it.